# How to find sum of a column in subquery result?

Tags: mysql

I have to calculate sum of a column which I got after join with a table

```
SELECT 
  fee_amount 
FROM bill 
  INNER JOIN status 
  ON bill_status_id=status_id 

  INNER JOIN user
  ON bill_user_id =user_id 
WHERE  bill_active='Y'
```

I have to calculate SUM of fee_amount returned after this, can I use below one?

```
SELECT 
  SUM(fee_amount) 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    fee_amount 
  FROM bill 
  INNER JOIN status 
  ON bill_status_id=status_id

  INNER JOIN user
  ON bill_user_id =user_id 
  WHERE  bill_active='Y'
)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried the option yourself? What error are you getting? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need use subquery for this, just add `SUM` in your first query.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(fee_amount)
FROM bill 
  INNER JOIN status 
  ON bill_status_id=status_id 

  INNER JOIN user
  ON bill_user_id =user_id 
WHERE  bill_active='Y'
```